# Sort the column by value if it is an integer/long and also by date if the column is a date column in ListView

Tags: vb.net

I am using the following code to sort a listview when clicking on the column:

```
Imports System.Collections
```

Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class ListViewColumnSorter
    Implements System.Collections.IComparer

```
Private ColumnToSort As Integer
Private OrderOfSort As SortOrder
Private ObjectCompare As CaseInsensitiveComparer

Public Sub New()
    ' Initialize the column to '0'.
    ColumnToSort = 0

    ' Initialize the sort order to 'none'.
    OrderOfSort = SortOrder.None

    ' Initialize the CaseInsensitiveComparer object.
    ObjectCompare = New CaseInsensitiveComparer()
End Sub

Public Function Compare(ByVal x As Object, ByVal y As Object) As Integer Implements IComparer.Compare
    Dim compareResult As Integer
    Dim listviewX As ListViewItem
    Dim listviewY As ListViewItem

    ' Cast the objects to be compared to ListViewItem objects.
    listviewX = CType(x, ListViewItem)
    listviewY = CType(y, ListViewItem)

    ' Compare the two items.
    compareResult = ObjectCompare.Compare(listviewX.SubItems(ColumnToSort).Text, listviewY.SubItems(ColumnToSort).Text)

    ' Calculate the correct return value based on the object 
    ' comparison.
    If (OrderOfSort = SortOrder.Ascending) Then
        ' Ascending sort is selected, return typical result of 
        ' compare operation.
        Return compareResult
    ElseIf (OrderOfSort = SortOrder.Descending) Then
        ' Descending sort is selected, return negative result of 
        ' compare operation.
        Return (-compareResult)
    Else
        ' Return '0' to indicate that they are equal.
        Return 0
    End If
End Function

Public Property SortColumn() As Integer
    Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
        ColumnToSort = Value
    End Set

    Get
        Return ColumnToSort
    End Get
End Property

Public Property Order() As SortOrder
    Set(ByVal Value As SortOrder)
        OrderOfSort = Value
    End Set

    Get
        Return OrderOfSort
    End Get
End Property
```

End Class

The msdn site for this is at: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319399

This is only sorting the columns via the text. I am wanting some help to modify this to sort the column by value if it is an integer/long and also by date if the column is a date column.

I can modify this line: compareResult = ObjectCompare.Compare(listviewX.SubItems(ColumnToSort).Text, listviewY.SubItems(ColumnToSort).Text) to sort via dates/integers etc, but I am having to manually code it. Is there a way to detect if the column I have clicked on is a date/long/integer column... maybe via tryparse?

thanks